# Save switch config in USB

Tags: switch, switchport, avaya

I want to save the configuration of an Avaya 4850GTS-PWR+ switch in a usb stick

So I plug the usb in the switch

Connect to the switch via putty using the Serial port in my laptop to the RJ45 Console port in the switch

If I run `show usb-host-port` I can see that the usb memory stick is being detected by the switch

[image]

So I run

```
copy config usb filename config.txt
```

and I get:

[image]

I'm using a Kingston 16 GB usb memory, already tried formatting it in FAT and NFTS, none worked

What could be wrong?

Comment: Your screenshot shows the USB stick is connected as physical device. But You cannot write the config file to the physical device, You need to **mount the filesystem** posessed on the USB stick for to write file. Do it...

Comment: Mount the file system... I'll try  to find the meaning for that, more hints would be further apreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the Installation Manual, only USB 1.1 and USB 2.0 are supported, along with FAT and FAT32 file systems. If I were you, I'd try to find a USB 2.0 2-4 GB stick and format it with FAT32.

> The switches feature a Universal Serial Bus (USB) port on the front
>   panel. Switch administrators can use the USB port to perform tasks,
>   previously performed through Trivial File Transfer Protocol (TFTP),
>   with a USB Mass Storage Device. The storage capacity of the USB device
>   in use limits file and system operations. Support is available only
>   for USB drives that comply with the Mass Storage subsection of the USB
>   1.1 and USB 2.0 specification. Support does not extend to third-party devices that do not comply with these standards. Off-the-shelf drives
>   that do not comply with these standards cannot operate with the
>   switch. Only FAT or FAT32 file systems are currently supported; USB
>   drives with NTFS file systems are not supported. Consult the
>   documentation provided with the USB drive to ensure compliance with
>   these standards.

https://downloads.avaya.com/css/P8/documents/100181383